# cannot deserialize with the "Id" attribute

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to deserialize a collection to class.
It seems that in case one of the fields named `Id`, I will get the error:

> base  {"An error occurred while deserializing the Address property of
>   class Person.LicenseEntity: Element 'Id' does not match any field or
>   property of class Person.Address"}    System.FormatException
>   {System.IO.FileFormatException}

However, changing the field name (e.g. to `Idd`) in both the class and the collection resolve the problem.

Is it possible that I'm not allowed to use the `Id` field?

Comment: sure would help if you would show the exact code / structure

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is because the Mongo C# driver deserializes the generated _id field from the document to the property named Id in your class. This means that your Id field has nowhere to go, and explains why changing the name of the Id to Idd allowed it to work.

As you are using a class called Address, I would perhaps name your field AddressId

Have a read of the [Mongo C# Driver Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/) I'm sure they will be a great help.