# Element 'id' does not match any field or property of error with nested classes

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've the following mongodb document schema;

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9d34ff781318afb9e8ab43"), 
    "name" : "Name", 
    "slug" : "slug",
    "services" : {
        "subservice" : {
            "id" : NumberInt(37030)
        }
    }
}
```

and then i define my classes as;

```
public class MainModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("slug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("services")]
    public ServicesDef Services { get; set; }

    public class ServicesDef 
    {
        [BsonElement("subservice")]
        public SubServiceDef SubService{ get; set; }

        public class SubServiceDef 
        {
            [BsonElement("id")]
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

But somehow when I query the document;

```
var result = await Repository.FindAsync(x => x.Slug == slug);
```

That services.subservice.id isn't properly registered and getting

Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class SubServiceDef.

Stuck here and looking for advice.

I think I'm having the same issue with [cannot deserialize with the "Id" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157954/cannot-deserialize-with-the-id-attribute) but seems there is solution yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long story short: it's all about conventions. MongoDB .NET driver exposes static class `ConventionRegistry` which allows you to register your own conventions (more [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/)). Additionally there are two "built-in" conventions `__defaults__` and `__attributes__`. Digging deeper (driver [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/14e046f23640ff9257c4edf53065b9a6768254d4/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Conventions/DefaultConventionPack.cs)) you can find that it registers one quite interesting convention:

```
new NamedIdMemberConvention(new [] { "Id", "id", "_id" })
```

Which means that `id` members will be considered as regular BSON _id elements.

How to fix that ?

You can get rid of default conventions

```
ConventionRegistry.Remove("__defaults__");
```

However automatically you will drop all the other driver conventions which is pretty risky. Alternatively you can create a fake property which will always be empty:

```
public class SubServiceDef
{
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId FakeId { get; set; }
}
```

or you can just use `BsonNoId` attribute which

> Specifies that the class's IdMember should be null.

```
[BsonNoId]
public class SubServiceDef
{
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So the convention will be setting your `id` as IdMember in class map but then during postprocessing this attribute will force IdMember to be null and your class will get deserialized succesfully

Comment: @Simons0n couldn't imagine that it can be a matter of life and death but good to hear that, stay safe!

Answer (score 2):

I like the answer from @mickl. The issue i had is couldn't update model and add attributes. Also I needed the original `Id`s and not `null`s after deserialization.

I tried `BsonClassMap` but i had so many sub models to update.

so, i ended up using your idea with removing default conventions.

```
public class MongoDbDefaultConventionPack : IConventionPack
{
    // private static fields
    private static readonly IConventionPack __defaultConventionPack = new MongoDbDefaultConventionPack();

    // private fields
    private readonly IEnumerable<IConvention> _conventions;

    // constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MongoDbDefaultConventionPack" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    private MongoDbDefaultConventionPack()
    {
        _conventions = new List<IConvention>
        {
            new ReadWriteMemberFinderConvention(),
            // new NamedIdMemberConvention(new [] { "Id", "id", "_id" }), changed to:
            new NamedIdMemberConvention(),
            new NamedExtraElementsMemberConvention(new [] { "ExtraElements" }),
            // new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(false), changed to:
            new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true),
            new ImmutableTypeClassMapConvention(),
            new NamedParameterCreatorMapConvention(),
            new StringObjectIdIdGeneratorConvention(), // should be before LookupIdGeneratorConvention
            new LookupIdGeneratorConvention()
        };
    }

    // public static properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static IConventionPack Instance
    {
        get { return __defaultConventionPack; }
    }

    // public properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the conventions.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<IConvention> Conventions
    {
        get { return _conventions; }
    }
}
```

and then replaced the config:

```
ConventionRegistry.Remove("__defaults__");
ConventionRegistry.Register("__defaults__", MongoDbDefaultConventionPack.Instance, t => true);
```

Worked great in my case as default convention. No more exceptions. Original Ids available