# C# Mongo serialization issue

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have an Id property in my class:

```
 [BsonElement("id")]
 public int Id {get; set;}
```

But when I try to serialize it to JSON using `BsonSerializer.Serialize()` I'm always getting

```
{ _id:0, .... }
```

The issue is i need to have  "id" instead "_id" in the output JSON.

The only workaround I found looks like:

```
  [BsonElement("id")]
  public int ExportId => Id; 

  [BsonIgnore]
  public int Id {get; set;}
```

But this solution looks "dirty", so is there any other way?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406944/element-id-does-not-match-any-field-or-property-of-error-with-nested-classes/55408372#55408372

Comment: Thank you, @mickl that solves my problem.